# My coroutine is running slower on Unity android aplication

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm working on a cookie clicker replica.

What happens is that I am using a `yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f)` to add the cookies per second to the cookie counter, and I want them to add up in a fast way, and not second per second.

The problem is that when I run it on my computer, it works perfectly, but when I run it on my android, it slowly adds the cookies to the counter.

According to my little knowledge, I would say it has to do with the FPS. I tried to use the `(Time.deltaTime * 0.1f)`, inside the `WaitForSeconds`, but it still works slowly in android. Also tried using the `Invoke()` method, but it works slowly too.

(I have the `StartCoroutine` inside the `Update` method.)
(When I put 1 second instead of 0.1f, it works fine, but it doesn't look good in terms of appearance.)

```cs
 IEnumerator Rps()
 {
     Stats.CookiesTotal = Stats.CookiesTotal + Stats.cookiesPerSecond;
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime * 0.1f);
     yield return null;
 }
 private void Update()
 {
     StartCoroutine(Rps());
     openSlot(price1text, price1, slot1);
     openSlot(price2text, price2, slot2);
     openSlot(price3text, price3, slot3);
 }
```

Comment: You start a coroutine in update. That can go bad. You need to do debugging and show it and your code.

Comment: im stuck on this for a while, i also tried to put the coroutine in  start method, but what i need is to add the cookies every second, and for that i also tried a while inside the IEnumerator but nothing works properly

Comment: You havent read how most of that works have you. Put a loop in the coroutine and start it at start. And ditch the extra yield

Comment: Don't use coroutines as they teach bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the coroutine from `Update()` which is framerate dependent.
So on a 60 fps machine, it will run `Rps()` 60 times, while on a 30 fps machine, it will run `Rps()` 30 times. Thus a faster fps machine will generate cookies faster.
Also note that the `WaitForSeconds` is occurring *after* you have increased the cookie amount which means it is delaying nothing at all, so in effect, this code is the same as:

```
private void Update()
{
    Stats.CookiesTotal = Stats.CookiesTotal + Stats.cookiesPerSecond;
    //...
}
```

As others have suggested, using coroutines this way in `Update()` is not ideal. It is possible to achieve a coroutined constant cookie increase every 0.1s by starting a coroutine in `Start()` and having an infinite loop inside the coroutine which increases cookie count and waits for X time. You will need to be **very mindful of managing that infinite loop coroutine**.
(This code is not tested but should give you the general idea)

```
private IEnumerator countCookiesCoroutine;

IEnumerator Rps()
{
    while (true){
        Stats.CookiesTotal = Stats.CookiesTotal + Stats.cookiesPerSecond;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
}

private void Start()
{
    countCookiesCoroutine = Rps();
    StartCoroutine(countCookiesCoroutine);
}
```

A more straightforward approach, especially if you are working with large numbers of cookies and precision is not important, might be to increment the cookie count in `FixedUpdate()` based on the physics time step, such as:

```
private void FixedUpdate(){
    Stats.CookiesTotal = Stats.CookiesTotal + (Stats.cookiesPerSecond * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

This will make the cookie rate increase as smoothly as physics updates and framerate independent. The reason I have used `FixedTime()` rather than `Update()` is because `Update()` is framerate dependant and even with `Time.deltaTime` faster machines will still collect cookies faster due to the higher compound cookie interest being calculated more frequently than on slower fps machines.

You may also need to wrap the display of the cookie numbers in a `Mathf.Floor()` if displaying decimals is undesirable.

Comment: Dude you actually saved me, the FixedUpdate() was the solution, wich is weird because i already tried it before, but now it works tsm